# How do I use Html Form Helper in a Html Helper extension method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I use the same form in two places. So I thought i could write an html helper extension method to minimize duplication. But I don't know how to use the html form helpers in an extension method.

Comment: Form helper renders only the `form` tag. Elements inside the tag are not affected by it. So there is no reuse unless you add some custom attributes to the `Form` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a partialView for your form to minimize duplication:

MainView:

```
@Html.Partial("MyCommonForm", Model.ObjectThatMyFormNeed)
```

Partial:

```
@model ObjectThatMyFormNeed

@using(Html.BeginForm(...))
{
   @*Form content*@
}
```

Comment: thanks. I never used partial views before. But I know the concept from cakePHP where they are called 'elements'.